# Cannot POST form - ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I'm learing ExpressJS, i want to do the login part , but i gave me this 
Cannot POST /login
im using the post method why it gave me this error 
here a detailed post , thank you in advance for helping me

html part

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" >
    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The route.js

```
  router.post('/login'),(req,res)=>{
             var username= req.body.name;
             var password = req.body.password;
             con.query('SELECT * FROM authentication  WHERE username = ?',username, function (error, results, fields) {
             if (error) {
               // console.log("error ocurred",error);
               res.send({
                 "code":400,
                 "failed":"error ocurred"
               })
             }else{
               // console.log('The solution is: ', results);
               if(results.length >0){
                 if(results[0].password == password){
                   res.send({
                     "code":200,
                     "success":"login sucessfull"
                       });
                 }
                 else{
                   res.send({
                     "code":204,
                     "success":"username and password does not match"
                       });
                 }
               }
               else{
                 res.send({
                   "code":204,
                   "success":"username does not exits"
                     });
               }
             }
             });   
    }
module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const indexRouter = require('./routes/route')
const con = require('./models/db')
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
 }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
console.log(__dirname)
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use('/',indexRouter)
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('it started on 5000'))
```

when trying to post this form i'm getting:
Cannot POST /login
what am i missing here?

Comment: you use app.use('/', indexRouter) can you send indexRouter middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle **current page**, not '/login' page in route.js :

```
router.post('/', //...
```

Instead of writing

```
router.post('/login', //...
```

Because you sent the form data to the **current page** not to the **'/login' page**

> **Why current page ?**
>   Because, you didn't define action attribute in your form

Comment: i defined the action in the form and i changed to this router.post('/', //... as u said but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to define form action

`<form action="/login" method="post">`

But I recommend you to use js for sending requests

```
fetch('/login', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(yourFormData),
     // ...another Opts if it needs
})
```

Also it can be problem with your server code because I don't see defining router in **indexRouter** file, you should add it:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// then your code:
router.post('/login', loginController);
```

But you can add this line for check post requests:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.status(201).json(req.body); // or console.log
});
```

Comment: i added action into form but still not working and its not showing any errors